# Enable .htaccess on ubuntu server

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, webserver, htaccess

I am looking to enable .htaccess in my Ubuntu server, I have ssh access and have attempted:

`sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/default`
and changing `AllowOverride` from none to all under directory /var/www/ , but that causes my server to give me a 500 Internal Sever Error message...

Any solutions?

Comment: check whether mod_rewrite module is enabled.

Comment: Ok I'll see, mind explaining how to check if its enabled?

Comment: try `sudo a2enmod rewrite` and follow it up with `sudo service apache2 restart`. If you're still getting an error, edit your question & add the contents of `.htaccess` & `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` file

Comment: Ok cool, that fixed the problem. Thank you so much! +1

Comment: welcome, I've moved the comment to an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, merely changing overrides isn't enough to enableURL rewrite - you'll have to enable Rewrite module.

You can do so by typing

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

and then restart Apache service

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

That should do the trick.